# iOS App looks good on iPhone but weirdly zoomed on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, responsive-design

I have just finished my App in xCode and have always run it on an iPhone where everything looks great. Now, I ran it for the first time on an iPad and it doesn't have the "responsivenes" I was hoping for. Instead, the whole app view is just awkardly zoomed to fit an iPad screen.

Here is the app on an iPhone:
[image]

Here is the app on an iPad:
[image]

I don't know if you can see it well, but the labels etc. look very pixelled on the iPad, because of the weird zoom and there is a black margin around the whole app. In my Storboard, I get the view that I want. The labels and buttons stay in the same size as in the iPhone.

Can someone explain why this is happening? I think I may have some wrong settings in my info.plist, but after researching, I can't figure out what...

Comment: Hello,

If you try to go to your app, General and set the application only for iPad it will work perfectly on the ipad right?

Comment: either you have not made a true universal app or you dont have the required launchImages (Default.pngs) ?

Comment: Where can I set the application only for iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Universal]

Change devices to universal in deployment target. And adjust your constraints to support iPad. Black border confirms that it is trying to run iPhone build on iPad and it does not designed to run iPad.

Hope it helps

Comment: Aaaah that was it. Thank you very much! I knew it probably was a small change, but I just didn't find it because I was only looking at my plist file

Comment: Great. Please accept my answer if you are happy with it